# Which R package for a Probability Plot Correlation Coefficient Plot

Tags: r

I want to know whether there is a canned function in an R package which produces PPCC plots - and, if so, which.

I have searched online (on the full name, partial names and the abbreviation) with no result; I have used the "??" function on my R GUI (I have downloaded all but the most specialised task views), again with no result.

Not for the first time, I'm up against the montrously perverse non-searchability inherent in the letter 'R'!

All help gratefully received.

Comment: It helps to search for "[R]" or "Rproject" instead of just the letter R…

Comment: Try http://www.rseek.org/

Comment: Why not describe what this is supposed to be? Perhaps with a link to a site that describes such an entity? Searching for "Probability Plot Correlation Coefficient Plot" in sites that describe R's use will be almost as difficult as searching for "R" because those words are so generic.

Comment: have you seen this discussion https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-August/037425.html?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try

```
plot(gofTest(x,test="ppcc",distribution))
```